# Trigonometric functions in system of equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, systems-of-equations

Can anyone please explain to me what exactly was done in the encircled two lines and why? I've tried figuring it out but I just can't make any sense of it.

Thank you for your time.
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/133T1.jpg)

[image: Photo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have added the two equations:
\begin{align}c_2^{'}(x)\cos^2x&=\sin x \cos^2x \tag{1}\\
c_2^{'}(x)\sin^2x&=0   \tag{2}
\end{align}
Now, add them;
$$c_2^{'}(x)[\cos^2x+\sin^2x]=\sin x \cos^2x.$$
Since, $\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$, you get $c_2^{'}(x)=\sin x \cos^2x$.